# Program Counter register values for a Java program

Tags: java, profiling

Is it possible to obtain the program counter (PC) register values of a running Java application, particularly one running in an Android emulator? gprof, for example, randomly samples PC register values in order to find which function is consuming the running time of the program. Does such a concept even make sense with the JVM? To clarify, I would like actual values of the program counter.

Also, is there some way I can measure how "spread out" the code is in memory? This can somewhat be measured in a regular program by looking at the range of addresses returned by objdump. However, this approach does not handle address of shared libraries, which again is a concept I don't understand in the context of the JVM.

Comment: Since Dalvik is very different from normal JVMs, there almost certainly won't be a solution that works for both.

Answer (score 0):

Many Java profilers like [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) can do sampling-based profiling, which probably works like you describe.

As for code memory usage, this is what the "permanent generation" (PermGen) of the garbage collector mainly contains; VisualVM can display that as well.

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear enough in the original question; I actually want the values of the program counters to get an idea of the spread of the layout of the program. Ideally, I would like a histogram of the PC values too.

Comment: @arunchaganty: Take a look at the JVMTI API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html - if it's not in there, you can't do it. But it usually doesn't make much sense to go down to that level with Java.

Comment: @Micheal Thank you for that reference. The `jlocation` format apparently can correspond to the native machine location. It also seems like `GetFrameLocation` might give the relevant information. Would I have to write my own tool in order to get this information though?