# Program Counter values of an executing Java Program

Tags: java, code-coverage, program-counter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Program Counter register values for a Java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295543/program-counter-register-values-for-a-java-program)

Is it possible to obtain the program counter (PC) register values of a running Java application?

Comment: Java was meant to be platform independent. Are you sure your requirement is correct. Are you writing a new code coverage tool? You may start from existing tools like cobertura/eclemma-jacoco

Comment: You may want to have a look at http://visualvm.java.net/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you want to go about it. For example, if via the JVM Tool Interface, there is an exposed function named [`GetFrameLocation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#GetFrameLocation). This should be equivalent to the program counter.

```
jvmtiEnv *penv;
...
jmethodID cur_method;
jlocation cur_loc;
(*penv)->GetFrameLocation(0, 0, &cur_method, &cur_loc);
```